# $q.all in service returning an empty object in controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http, angular-promise

Hello I have had some trouble with this api call for a while. When I make this API call the console.log in my service returns what I need but the controller does not receive it and returns an empty object. I think I may be doing something wrong when I return my promises but I can't find the problem. I am Currently using $q.all() to chain multiple get requests.

Here is my code For my controller function:

```
    $scope.getData = function(input) {
    exampleService.getData(input)
        .then(function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            $scope.savedData = data;
    }, function(error) {
          alert(error); // just sends an alert with -1 if error
    });
};
```

Now here is my service function

```
this.getData = function(input) {
$q.all([
    $http.get(url1),
    $http.get(url2)
]).then(function(response) {
    console.log(response); //returns array of objects that I want
    return response;
});
return $q.all();
};
```

Now I tried to return ***$q.all().promises*** but I got an error in my console saying:

> cannot read property 'then' of undefined

I ultimately want to access one property in each object in the array, which is also a object nested in the object for example

```
var returnedPromise = [
     {dataIDontNeed:1, {dataIwant}},
     {dataIDontNeed:2, {dataIwant}},
     {dataIDontNeed:3, {dataIwant}}
]
```

I would like to know if there is a way to get that ***dataIwant*** object from the array of objects before I send back the promise. If anyone could help me out I would be very grateful

Comment: Regarding your second question (not the obvious typo), you can simply `return` something else than the `response` from that `then` callback.

Answer (score 3):

You are returning another, empty, copy of $q. Just return the original $q.all promise from the service

```
return $q.all([ $http.get(url1), $http.get(url2) ]);
```

And do this in the controller:

```
service.getData({}).then(...
```

If you want to transform the results just chain another promise that's resolved right away to the all function. With the data looking the way you say, just delete the property you don't want:

```
return $q.all([ $http.get(url1), $http.get(url2) ]).
then(function(results){
    return results.map(function(each){
        delete each.dataIDontNeed;
        return each;
    });
    });
```

Handle it just the same way in the controller.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Is there any solution you have in mind for the second part of my question?